# Comparing a hashed password with Active Directory

Tags: .net, ldap

I believe I know the answer to this already but wanted to post and see if anyone had any additional thoughts. Current code is hashing the password (MD5, SHA1, immaterial in this case) before it sends it over to a Web service. The Web service uses the hashed password and compares it against a database which is hashed. We want to provide similar functionality for AD but don't really want to send the password across to the service in clear text. SSL is in the environment as well and we could do a Binary encoding of some sort to help but I was curious if there is any functionality in the directory services classes to compare the AD password to a hashed value during the login simulation. My suspicion is no.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way to do it with LDAP, but it can be done with Kerberos. A good starting point is [Kerberos Authentication Technical Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739058%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) on technet.

You may also want to check [Logon and Authentication Technologies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780455%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), which is the parent article and list a bunch of ways to authenticate against AD, with which I am not familiar.

Answer (score 0):

Most LDAP implementaitons, but maybe not AD, support http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Authentication_and_Security_Layer which may work for you here.

Using TLS/SSL and a simple bind is as secure as your solution as the password would never be exposed on the wire in cleartext.

-jim